# How to select just the max timestamp rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, timestamp, max, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition

So I have some data as follows:

```
USER_ID                 TIMESTAMP   data  data2
   0001   2021-05-09 12:13:03.445    tim     44
   0002   2021-05-09 13:13:03.445    rob    543
   0002   2021-05-09 11:13:03.445   jeff    252
   0003   2021-05-09 09:13:03.445  perry    333
   0002   2021-05-09 12:13:03.445   carl    333
   0003   2021-05-09 16:13:03.445  mitch      1
```

Now usually I write the following to get the min timestamp records:

```
WITH form_raw AS (
    select df.*,
        rank() over (
            partition by user_ID
            order by timestamp
        ) as num
    FROM df
)
    select *
    from form_raw
    where num = 1
)
```

But how can I do this for the max timestamp? I can easily do this with num = 1 for min but because there are different numbers of entries for each user_id, what do I do to make it max timestamp?

Final Output:

```
USER_ID                 TIMESTAMP   data  data2
   0001   2021-05-09 12:13:03.445    tim     44
   0002   2021-05-09 13:13:03.445    rob    543
   0003   2021-05-09 16:13:03.445  mitch      1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just order by desc:

```
select * from 
(  
  select *,rank() over (partition by user_ID order by timestamp desc) as num
  FROM df
) t
where num = 1
```